# PyCharm doesn't show the preview panel for Markdown files after updating

Tags: pycharm

I recently updated my PyCharm from an old (2020) version to the newest one (2022.2). Since then my Markdown preview isn't showing when edition Markdown files.

I tried:

- disabling and reactivating the Markdown plugin
- restarting PyCharm
- restarting the PC
- clicking the following options:

[image: Help search preview]

but upon clicking i.e. "Editor and Preview" (and the other "OFF"-labled options as well) nothing happens.

How can I reactivate the preview window?

Comment: Thanks, @Jojotyp! Clicking _Editor and Preview_ did show it again for me. I still can't find how to bring that floating panel back, where we can choose between the modes.

Answer (score 1):

What works for me was `click right on the file -> override file type -> choose markdown`

If not work, then install another markdown plugin.

Answer (score 1):

> Does it help if you add `ide.browser.jcef.gpu.disable=true` in Help | Edit Custom Properties and restart the IDE?

*Taken from a comment by Serge Baranov at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-305517*

Answer (score 0):

Try to re-install pyCharm in the latest version to see if it works or not in preview

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).